# Function in Script not working in editor while calling function of One Script in Another Script but console returns the correct values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, hololens

The function IncreaseRadius in OrbitFireball script attached to CircleMovementTarget GameObject when called from editProperties Script attached to Radius (+) GameObject does not return the change in values in editor or the original script i.e. OrbitFireball (see on the right in the script OribtFireball, OrbitDistance = 0.1) even when the Console returns the changes just fine (see the console the values increase on hitting the Radius (+) icon).

Unity Version Used: 2017.2.1f1

[image: App]

...

```
 using HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule;
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class OrbitFireball : MonoBehaviour, IInputClickHandler {

     public Transform target;
     public float orbitDistance = 0.1f;
     public float orbitDegreesPerSec = 90.0f;

     public GameObject Ball;


         // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {

     }

     void Orbit()
     {
         if(target != null)
         {
             // Keep us at orbitDistance from target
             transform.position = target.position + (transform.position - target.position).normalized * orbitDistance;
             transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.back, orbitDegreesPerSec * Time.deltaTime);

             // Ball up and down
             Ball.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, target.position.z);

         }
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

        Orbit(); 
     }


    public void increaseRadius()
    {
        if (orbitDistance <= 0.3f)
        {
            orbitDistance += 0.1f;
            Debug.Log(orbitDistance);
        }
    }

    public void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule;
using UnityEngine;

public class editProperties : OrbitFireball, IInputClickHandler {

    public void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
    {
        if (gameObject.tag == "RadiusPlus")
        {
            increaseRadius();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Believe this just has to do with how the inspector updates. I would guess it will work if you force a Repaint().

Comment: @ryeMoss Is the method used by some other name in Unity or is there any additional class/namespace to be included to call it? 
I tried Repaint() and this.Update() and neither works. I think the logic you are suggesting is correct, but unfortunately I don't know what the correct solution is.

Comment: When you say you "change the values in the editor" do you mean in the inspector tab, or in the game window?  If you are changing values using the inspector tab, try adding an OnValidate() method to check when the values are changed.  Note that changes in the inspector do not trigger some things you might expect, for example it bypasses public setters and triggers.  You may need to trigger actions using OnValidate () to make your game respond to inspector changes.

Comment: @Jethro I meant game window, when I actually click on the Menu Icon clicking which is supposed to change these values.